# Picking correct date from datepicker and restricting user from entering in an incorrect date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery-UI date picker for picking out a date. My goal is to have the user pick the correct date (MM/DD/YYYY) without letting them modify it incorrectly. This is a required field.

I've managed to do that by using date picker, and to make sure the user doesn't type anything incorrect like 19/01/2017 (the month is incorrect) I added `.on('keypress', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); })` this line of code does not allow the user to write anything in the input box.

The next thing i tried with my date picker input box is making it readonly so i don't have to use that line of code, but making it read only takes away the required functionalities in form submit.

**Problem**

The issue is all of my other input box is now disabled, meaning i can't type in any of them.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();

  }).on('keypress', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/findbrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



  <div class="form-group">
    <p>Date </p><input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker" required></p>
    <p>Name: </p><input type="text" name="LastName">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently adding the event handler to the entire document, and you actually just want to add it to the datepicker element. See below:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker().on('keypress', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    })
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/findbrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



  <div class="form-group">
    <p>Date </p><input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker" required></p>
    <p>Name: </p><input type="text" name="LastName">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By directly calling the function you are disabling everything on the window element by using preventDefault.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker().on('keypress', function(e) {
      preventDefault(e);
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/findbrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



  <div class="form-group">
    <p>Date </p><input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker" required></p>
    <p>Name: </p><input type="text" name="LastName">
  </div>
```